# Xamarin.Forms How to switch pages using MVVMLight

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light, .net-standard

I'm currently working on a Xamarin.forms project using **.NET Standard** as code sharing strategy. I try to use the MVVM pattern by using the **MvvmLightLibsStd10** library. I already successfully setup the MVVM structure by using this tutorial:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/build-xamarinforms-net-standard-mvvm-light-app-rafael-carvalho

I can't use Navigation.PushAsync(new Page()); because it only works in code behind and not in the ViewModel.

I already tried to Pass Navigation trough the VM constructor, like describe over here:
[Xamarin.form Page Navigation in mvvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254396/xamarin-form-page-navigation-in-mvvm)

But when I try this method, an error occurred at "LoadApplication(new DemoMVVM2.App());" in MainPage.

How can I switch pages using MVVM Xamarin.Forms with MVVMLight (based on the code from my first url)?

but I have no Idea how I can switch Pages via the ViewModel and keeping the header with back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a callback to your ViewModel(VM) and on `Command` or whatever action call your navigation code which is in your page (View). this way you can keep your navigation code in your page and your binding logic in your ViewModel.

```
interface NavHandler{
    void navigateToSomeView();
}

public class MyPage : ContentPage,NavHandler{
     public MyPage(){
         BindingContext = new MyViewModel(this);
     }
     void navigateToSomeView(){
         Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
     }
} 

public class MyViewModel{
    NavHandler handler;
    public MyViewModel(NavHandler handler){
        this.handler = handler
    }
    //Your action
    this.btnClicked = new Command(async()=>{
        handler.navigateToSomeView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your advice but now, everytime when I run the app, whenever it is UWP or Android, I got 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.'

However App only have 1 ctor which actually is parameterless.

You can download my source code over here:
https:// we.tl/byHWdsjyFN

Comment: you should call constructor with parameter as shown in the code above 
`BindingContext = new MainViewModel(this);` which is the constructor you have defined in your `MainViewModel.cs`

Answer (score 1):

Generally when working with MVVMLight you'll be using a `NavigationService`.
This class can be constructor injected in your VM, thanks to the build in IOC in MVVMLight.
With it you can do `Navigate` and `GoBack` in your VM, triggering a real navigation on the current stack.

Only thing that you maybe missed, is the fact that you need to write one yourself for Xamarin forms.
But Laurent Bugnion ( the owner of MVVMLight ) supplied an example available here:
https://github.com/lbugnion/sample-2016-vslive-crossplatform/blob/master/Flowers/Flowers.Forms/Flowers.Forms/Helpers/NavigationService.cs